# kubuntu 17.10 and nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I just installed kubuntu 17.10 on a lenovo Y700 laptop, and tried to install nvidia driver by doing :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt purge 'nvidia-*'
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install nvidia-384
```

After restarting, it results in a black screen.

1) How can I have at least to a Konsole, or an ssh connection to the laptop in order to uninstall nvidia drivers and try fixes? Indeed I have been doing fresh installations o kubuntu several times now?

2) Any fix for this issue? my NVIDIA is GTX 960M

Thanks or help

Answer (score 6):

I believe you did everything right, only do

```
sudo apt purge nvidia* 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Also if you have been doing fresh reinstallations of Kubuntu and failing, try opening Gparted or another partition manager on the live USB version, then delete all Kubuntu partitions. Then reinstall the OS.

Comment: Thanks... I have been reinstalling the OS or 5 times now. As or the nvidia version, I checked on nvidia's site that 384 is the current version for my system

Comment: Try the solution and tell me if it works

Comment: I tried it. It turns out that it selects the version 304 of the driver, even i a research on nvidia's site indicates version 384. I could restart the pc and boot into it after installation, but I cannot be sure that the driver is indeed loaded and used. or example, trying a command like 'nvidia-smi' results in ile not foud

Comment: You should be able to see Nvidia X Server Settings in the apps list after a reboot

Comment: I try that. For the moment, clicking on the K menu reezes the computer..

Comment: The proper kommand for this is nvidia-settings. also in your question it says you have a black screen. Now you say that the kubuntu menu freezes the computer. Did my solutions fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my comment (my second comment, beginning by "I tried... "), when I try your solution, it installs the version 304 o the driver, and I log in and the computer works fine. I see the nvidia X server settings in the app list. Does it mean nvidia is currently used?
In that case,  why doesn't nvidia-smi command work on command line?  Thanks a lot or this dialogue and for the precious help

Comment: Moreover, a simple C++ program that shows a window (using SDL) freezes the computer :(((((.. I do not think NVIDIA driver is being used.. By the way I tried also to blacklist some programs as advised in tis video, and no better result https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVTsemATIyI

Comment: You have to **enable** the external GPU in the Nvidia X Server Settings,  go to PRIME Profiles, and press NVIDIA ( Performance Mode ). It will definently be enabled after that. Right now I am 78 percent sure it is being used.

Comment: OK. I will try that. For the moment, when I go to "Driver manager software", the radio button checked is "Using X.org X server - Nouveau ...."

Comment: By the way I stop or the moment and continue tomorrow. 3 am here now (United kingdom). Thanks a lot or your help, and hope to continue tomorrow

Comment: Okay then, good night! :)

Comment: Also if there are only two options in Nvidia X Server Settings, try to install the Driver manager software version

Comment: Thank.. now when I call nvidia-settings I have the same screen as here : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342538    that is why I think nvidia is not even taken into accout

Comment: this solved it

     sudo apt purge nvidia*
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt upgrade
    sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: @AutoBootDisk Please read my other comment and understand that `nvidia-current` is only for legacy hardware. Please do NOT recommended it in comments and especially not in answers that are supposed to meet certain "quality standards".

Comment: @volatile - if that answer solved it for you, please mark AutoBootDisk's answer as the solution, as it will help others (like myself) in the future. AutoBookDisk's answer solved this problem for me too (also running Kubuntu 17.10).

Comment: @Vanessa Deagan I posted the solution that worked for me in my last comment. (Dec 3 '17 at 12:29 ). I just posted it again now as an answer and accepted it, to highlight it a little more. I hope that helps. And thanks again to all people that took some time to help, and hopefully this will help other people also